# Special character should not be allowed in NAME box

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I don't want my user to register his/her name with characters like "!@#$%^&*()_+" how should I do this using jQuery and AJAX?

this is my code:

```
    function registerDialog(){ 

var message = '';

if(loginBox != ''){ 
    $.modal.close();
}


var html =  

             '<div>'
             +'<h4 style="background:#DADEE7;padding:10px;border:1px solid #ccc;"><i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right "></i> Register</h4>'
             +'<input type="email" id="emailBox" placeholder="Email Address" style="width:90%; margin:10px auto 3px 10px;"/>'
             +'<input type="password" id="passwordBox" placeholder="Password" style="width:90%; margin:10px auto 3px 10px;"/>'
             +'<input type="text" id="realNameBox" style="width:90%;margin:10px auto 10px 10px;" placeholder="Complete Name."style="width:90%; margin:10px auto 3px 10px;" onkeypress="return restrictCharacters(this, event, alphaOnly);" />'
             +'<p id="infoBox" style="width:90%;margin-left:10px;margin-bottom:5px;"></p>'
             +'<p id="infoBox2" style="width:90%;margin-left:10px;margin-bottom:5px;"></p>'
             +'<p style="text-align:right;">'
             +'<button style="padding:5px;margin-right:5px;" id="signUpBtn">Submit</button>'
             +'<button style="padding:5px;margin-right:20px;" id="cancelBtn">Cancel</button>'
             +'</p>'
             +'</div>'



registerBox = $.modal(html, {
    closeHTML:"",
    containerCss:{
        backgroundColor:"#fff", 
        borderColor:"#fff", 
        minHeight: 250, 
        width: ($(window).width() > 320)? 320 : $(window).width() - 10,
        padding:0 
    },
    overlayClose:true,
    opacity:80,
    overlayCss: {
        backgroundColor:"#000"
    },
        onShow : function (dialog) {


            $("#signUpBtn",dialog.data).click(function(){

                      var email = $('#emailBox').val();
                      var passwordBox = $('#passwordBox').val();
                      var realNameBox = $('#realNameBox').val();

                          if(email != '' && passwordBox != '' && realNameBox != '' && validateEmail(email) && filterName(realNameBox)){



                              $.ajax({
                                  type  : 'get',
                                  async : false,
                                  url: baseUrl+'/Index/register',
                                  data:{
                                        email   : email,
                                        password: passwordBox,
                                        realname: realNameBox
                                  },
                                  error: function(req,error){ 
                                    console.log(req.statusText);
                                  },
                                  dataType: 'json',
                                  cache: false,
                                  success   : function(msg){  

                                    if(msg.status == "OK"){ 
                                        message = 'Successfully Registered.';
                                        alert(message);
                                        window.location.reload();
                                    }else{
                                        message = 'Registration failed, Email address already used.';
                                        $('#infoBox').html(message).css('color', 'red');
                                        return false;
                                    } 
                                }

                               });
                          }else{  
                              if(email == ''){$('#emailBox').addClass('border-red');}else{$('#emailBox').removeClass('border-red');}
                              if(passwordBox == ''){$('#passwordBox').addClass('border-red');}else{$('#passwordBox').removeClass('border-red');}
                              if(realNameBox == ''){$('#realNameBox').addClass('border-red');}else{$('#realNameBox').removeClass('border-red');}
                              $('#infoBox').html('Please complete or correct the fields above marked in red.');

                              if(validateEmail(email) == false){
                                  $('#emailBox').addClass('border-red'); 
                              }else{
                                  $('#emailBox').removeClass('border-red'); 
                              }

                              return false;
                          }


            });




            $('#realNameBox').keypress(function(e){
                 if (e.which == 13) {
                     $("#signUpBtn",dialog.data).click();

                 }  
            });

            $("#cancelBtn",dialog.data).click(function(){

                var email = $('#emailBox').val('');
                var passwordBox = $('#passwordBox').val('');

                $.modal.close();
            });
        },
        onOpen: function (dialog) {
            dialog.overlay.fadeIn('fast', function () {
                dialog.data.hide();
                dialog.container.fadeIn('fast', function () {
                    dialog.data.slideDown('fast');   
                });
            });
        },
        onClose: function (dialog) {
            dialog.data.fadeOut('fast', function () {
                dialog.overlay.slideUp('fast', function () {
                    $.modal.close();
                });
            });

        }
});
}
```

I tried putting some code to restrict the text box from accepting the special characters but it seems like it's not working.

Comment: Food for thought: no matter what restrictions you have client-side, be sure to enforce these restriction server-side, too. Just because you don't allow me to send something to your server with JavaScript doesn't mean I can't send it to your server by another means.

Comment: what do you mean? @ljacqu

Comment: It's not directly related to your problem. If you're sending this data to a page of yours, just be sure to validate the user input before saving it. An evil user (gasp!) can easily circumvent any restrictions you impose through JavaScript, so your server-side code needs to be ready for _anything_. ;)

Comment: @ljacqu : how can i bypass it? i already filtered it but i don't know how to bypass it LOL

Comment: A basic example: set up a HTML form on your computer where you can enter whatever you want and then send it to that page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Borrowing from Valentin Jacquemin's regex approach above and using jQuery:

```
$(function(){
    $('input, textarea').keyup( function(){
        var inputs = $(this).val();
        $(this).val(inputs.replace(/[^a-z0-9\s]/gi, ''));   
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/r3wt/wBLxL/11/

Replaces all non alphanumeric charachters.

Comment: +1 for the jsfiddle and for validating with a "whitelist" approach, rather than looking for bad characters, which would surely not be comprehensive.

Comment: what if i just want to use this code for just a specific textbox?

Answer (score 0):

A regex is probably the way to go:

`var isNameValid = /[!@#$%^&*()_+]/.test(realNameBox);`

As suggested by ljacqu in your question's comments, ensure you validate server-side too.

Comment: can i ask how should i validate the erver-side too? i am a newbie in this line. thanks

Comment: what language are you using server-side?

Answer (score 0):

Best way would be to use regular expresion:

```
 function isValid(str){
       return !/[!@#$%^&*()_+]/.test(str);
 }
```

the function will return true if the expresion does not copntain any of those characters.

As suggested in the comments make sure to do the same thing in php. You can use the same principle and use reg. expresion in php ie.:

```
 function isValid($str) {
    if (preg_match("/[!@#$%^&*()_+]/", $str)) return false;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: `*` and `()` should be escaped in the PHP code, possibly among others. In this context, it might make more sense to check for what is allowed, rather than disallowed.